# Is there a list of android devices?

Tags: android

I, i am creating a multi device support application.
Is it possible that i can get a list of devices on the basis of their Densities - mdpi,hdpi etc, because it is very hard to create layouts because even eclipse doesn't provide all the emulators for all the devices. There are more devices and less emulators.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one I have been referencing a lot: [Device List](http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/listdevice.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need this page:

http://www.android.com/devices/

The page listed all the devices that is officially certificated with Google - they are powered by Google services.